# School Population or Sample

Tags: survey

If I surveyed every K-5 teacher from a school system, is the population considered the School System and the sample considered every K-5 teacher?

Answer (score 5):

The "population" is just the name we give to the group you are ultimately interested in, so if you are only interested in these teachers from this school system then yes, that is your population.  If you sample them all then you have a full census of the population, and so your sample and population correspond.

However, if you are interested in all K-5 teachers, including those operating outside this school system (e.g., in other school systems in another country), and you are looking at these K-5 teachers in this school system as a sample of that, then in that case, your "population" would be the broader group of interest, and your sample is the ones you observed.

Comment: So, I only want the K-5 answers, and I did a census of that entire K-5 group, you are saying my population is the school system and my sample is the K-5 group. Correct?

Comment: No.  If you are only interested in the K-5 group you surveyed, then *that* is your population of interest.  Since you sampled all of them, you have a full census.  So in your case you would give descriptive information for your population, but there is no inference problem, since there are no unobserved people in the population.